# How to resolve 403 forbidden error while launching MarkLogic in windows?

Tags: admin, marklogic

403 Forbidden

> SEC-NOADMIN: (err:FOER0000) User does not have admin-ui privilege.
> in /MarkLogic/security.xqy, at 7110:7, in sec:check-admin() [1.0-ml]
> in /MarkLogic/Admin/lib/status-check.xqy, at 24:1, in adlib:status-check() [1.0-ml]
> in /, at 7:0 [1.0-ml]

Have tried to deploy gradle with same existing user name. After that, I am getting this error while launching MarkLogic. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: It is telling you that the user doesn't have the required privilege to use the Admin UI. What roles are assigned to the user that you are using? At a minimum, you need to have `admin-ui-user` for read-only access. https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/admin-guide/en/administrative--admin--interface/the-admin-ui-user-role.html